# ASIHttpRequest - delete cache after a certain time interval

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I'm using the [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library in my App and I'm trying to set the cache for a particular request so that it may be used up to a certain period of time (if no data is available from the server or there is no internet connection), beyond that it will reject/delete the cache, and so will not use it.

So what I am trying to get the request to do is, first check if it can retrive data online, if it cannot access it (for whatever reason, server is down or no internet connection is available) then use the cache, provided it is not expired.  The expiry of the cache I would like to set to a certain amount of time, such as 12 hours after which the data was saved to cache.

What I've tried so far is:

```
// Set secondsToCache on the request to override any expiry date for the content set by the server, and store 
// this response in the cache until secondsToCache seconds have elapsed
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setSecondsToCache:60*60*24*30]; // Cache for 30 days
```

This is taken from the example on the website.

However, this doesn't seem to have the effect that I would like, as described above.

How do I cache data for a certain amount of time, after which it is deleted from cache?

Comment: No effect really - I tested it with a 2 minute interval, so I set the seconds to 60*2 on setSecondsToCache, and waited 3 minutes, and it still uses the cached data when I put the iPhone to airplane mode.  So it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: what cachePolicy are you setting on the request?

Comment: [request setCachePolicy:ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];
    [request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];

That's what I have set at the moment, maybe the policies aren't compatible with setting the seconds to cache message?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a breakpoint in `canUseCachedDataForRequest` in `ASIDownloadCache.m`; single step through and see what route the code takes.

It should follow one of the paths that calls `isCachedDataCurrentForRequest`, which should return NO if the data has expired.

From looking at the [code](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIDownloadCache.m#L312) it appears that 'setSecondsToCache' should set the "X-ASIHTTPRequest-Expires" header in the cached object, which should make isCachedDataCurrentForRequest return NO - I think only debugging through is going to tell you at which point this is going wrong in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The method [request setSecondsToCache:xxx] seems doesn't work for expiration and it also doesn't work for cache. If you don't set

```
[request setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];
```

the cache will be removed after session down.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little bit old, but my code is still working on ios7.

```
-(NSData*)getResponseAsDataFromUrl:(NSURL*)sourceUrl andWithCachePolicy:(ASICachePolicy)cachePolicy andWithExpireDurationInSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)expireDuration{
 ASIHTTPRequest* request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:sourceUrl];
[request setCachePolicy:cachePolicy];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:30];

//We set the expireduration to a second we desire
[request setSecondsToCache:expireDuration];
NSError* error = [request error];
NSData* jsonData;
NSDictionary* cachedHeaderDict = [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] cachedResponseHeadersForURL:sourceUrl];
NSDate* expireDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
if([[cachedHeaderDict allKeys] containsObject:@"X-ASIHTTPRequest-Expires"]){
    NSNumber* cacheInterval = [cachedHeaderDict objectForKey:@"X-ASIHTTPRequest-Expires"];
    expireDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:cacheInterval.doubleValue];
}
switch ([now compare:expireDate]) {
    case -1:{
  //            NSLog(@"Cache has not been expired. Using cached response.");
        jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] pathToCachedResponseDataForURL:sourceUrl]];

    }
        break;
    default:{
   //            NSLog(@"Cache expired. Cleaning cached data.");
        [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] removeCachedDataForRequest:request];
    }
        break;
}

if(!jsonData){
    [request startSynchronous];
    if(!error){ //If there is no error, use the data
        jsonData = [request responseData];
        if(!jsonData)//This is here for cases where we get empty response and we dont want to store empty responses.
            [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] removeCachedDataForRequest:request];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"no response: %@",error.description);
        [[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache] removeCachedDataForRequest:request];
    }
    [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
    request = nil;
}
return jsonData;
}
```